# How to look for missing rows within a group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Consider the data below.  I am trying to find situations where in a specific RequestID, there is an `Attempt: 0`, but `Attempt: 2` is missing.

I've tried looking for `Attempt: 0` with a `WHERE` predicate and doing `NOT EXISTS ... Attempt: 2` in a subquery, but it doesn't return the right data.

How do I find the RequestIDs with missing `Attempt: 2`?

```
ID      Message       RequestID
635828  Attempt: 0    1
635968  Attempt: 1    1
641085  Attempt: 2    1
641230  Attempt: 3    1
643859  Attempt: 0    2
645991  Attempt: 1    2
650255  Attempt: 3    2
652388  Attempt: 0    3
654520  Attempt: 1    3
658785  Attempt: 3    3
```

Comment: Look up "gaps and islands" to get some ideas.

Comment: No time to give a full solution, but look into windowing function and lag/lead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists` like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.message = 'Attempt: 0' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.requestid = t.requestid and
                        t2.message = 'Attempt: 2'
                 );
```

Another possibility is aggregation:

```
select requestid
from t
where message in ('Attempt: 0', 'Attempt: 2')
group by requestid
having sum(case when message = 'Attempt: 2' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```